# Using Hibernate fetch profile with JPA Criteria API

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

Is it possible to use fetch profile along with JPA criteria API ?

Although, it's hibernate specific, but because it's configured 
in session level, and knowing that its purpose is to replace hibernate
static configuration of @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT), i'm wondering why it's ignoredin my case, is this the expected behavior of hibernate ?

here after a code snapshot of what i did.

```
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @OneToMany(cascade= {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE}, mappedBy="entityB", orphanRemoval= true, fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<EntityA> aList = new ArrayList<>();
```

```
<fetch-profile name="profile-for-select-A">
    <fetch entity="EntityB" association="aList" style="select"/>
</fetch-profile>
```

```
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public List<EntityB> find(){
        Session session  = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        session.enableFetchProfile("profile-for-select-A");
        CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<EntityB> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(EntityA.class);
        Root<EntityB> root = criteriaQuery.from(EntityB.class);
        criteriaQuery.distinct(true);
        TypedQuery<EntityB> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
        typedQuery.setFirstResult(0);
        typedQuery.setMaxResults(50);
        return typedQuery.getResultList();
    }
```

The aim of this, is to Fecth a lazy collection with select queries instead of join.

In case where the collection is eager, and using the same criteria query along with the static configuration, the lazy collection get initialized by select queries, and not a join.

Is this the right way to enable the profile ? or may it be enabled in a different session and not in the current session ?

Thx for any help